# Appscript that creates a new worksheet when new data is entered in Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I have an app script code that Creates a new workbook when new data is entered in Google Sheet. The code is below.

```
function myFunction() {
 // The code below creates a new spreadsheet "New Sheet Name" and logs the URL for it
var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create();
Logger.log(ssNew.getUrl());
}
```

I want the new spreadsheet name to be the last data entered in Column A and also the URL for the new workbook to be pasted in Column J of the same row as the last data in Column A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Creating a new Spreadsheet

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const nss = SpreadsheetApp.create(sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 1).getDisplayValue())
  sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(), 10).setValue(nss.getUrl());
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked! I have one more favor to ask of you. Can you edit the script so it would add the same people in the first Worksheet to the newly created worksheets?

Comment: Yes.  Please describe the content in ss that you wish copied.

Comment: I'm a new apps script user, I don't understand this

Comment: Do just wish to copy some sheets from one spreadsheet to another?If so which ones if no then what?

Comment: I meant that everything you provided in the last code worked perfectly.    I just want to add a function to it that shares the newly created worksheets with the same people the main sheet was shared to

Comment: Explain which worksheets

Comment: the ones created by the apps script that is being triggered by OnEdit Trigger

Comment: There is no onEdit described in this question.

Comment: yes, I created the onEdit trigger manually

Comment: Yes but the onedit function is not posted in this question so we don't know anything about it

Comment: I have rephrased the question here. 
     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72370305/apps-script-that-shares-a-google-sheet-to-a-specific-group-of-people         please do check it out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72370305/18872230

Answer (score 2):

From `I have an app script code that Creates a new workbook when new data is entered in Google Sheet.`, I thought that you might be running the script with the installable OnEdit trigger. But from your showing script, I thought that you might have wanted to directly run with the script editor. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var title = sheet.getRange("A" + lastRow).getValue();
  var ssNew = SpreadsheetApp.create(title);
  sheet.getRange("J" + lastRow).setValue(ssNew.getUrl());
}
```

- When this script is run, the title is retrieved from the column "A" of the last row. And, the URL of created Spreadsheet is put in the column "J" of the same row.

#### Reference:

- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)